# Can the objective function have multiple input variables except the optimizable variable?

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize

When use the scipy.optimize, the objective function I tried successfully can only take one variable, scalar or vector.

for example, this code works:

```
from scipy import optimize

def f(x, a=2, b=-5, c=3):
    return a*x*x+b*x+c

res=optimize.minimize_scalar(f)

print(res.x)
```

however, if what I want is to track the res.x changing with a, b, c? the following code doesn't work, but how to make it work?

```
from scipy import optimize

def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x*x+b*x+c

def change(a, b, c):
    res=optimize.minimize_scalar(f(x, a, b, c))
    print(res.x)
    return res.x

change(3, 2, 1)
change(3, -9, 0)
```

the only way I can think of is like this:

```
from scipy import optimize

def change(a, b, c):
    def f(x):
        return a*x*x+b*x+c
    res=optimize.minimize_scalar(f)
    print(res.x)
    return res.x

change(3, 2, 1)
change(3, -9, 0)
```

function inside another function makes me feel bad, is there any other way? Thanks.

Comment: `a,b,c` can be passed in via the `args` parameter (pay attention to the `tuple` requirement).

Comment: I don't get your meanning, could you show some codes? Thank you very much!

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar - Do you see the `args` parameter??

Comment: Thanks, I just saw it, ha, wondering how to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply doing this will work:

```
from scipy import optimize

def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x*x+b*x+c

def change(a, b, c):
    tup=(a, b, c)
    res=optimize.minimize_scalar(f, args=tup)
    print(res.x)
    return res.x

change(3, 2, 1)
change(3, -9, 0)
```